# How to print both strings in a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm having trouble printing both the name in the list and the email. The beginning part of the code was already pre written and my attempt is the for loop. If anybody would be able to help me that would be greatly appreciated.

Here are the directions:

Write a for loop to print each contact in contact_emails. Sample output for the given program:

```
mike.filt@bmail.com is Mike Filt  
s.reyn@email.com is Sue Reyn  
narty042@nmail.com is Nate Arty
```

Code:

```
contact_emails = {
'Sue Reyn' : 's.reyn@email.com',
'Mike Filt': 'mike.filt@bmail.com',
'Nate Arty': 'narty042@nmail.com'
}

for email in contact_emails:
print('%s is %s' % (email, contact_emails(email)))
```

Comment: You're close... `print('%s is %s' % (contact_emails[email], email))`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you need to use square brackets(`[]`) instead of parenthesis(`()`). Like so:

```
for email in contact_emails:
    print('%s is %s' % (contact_emails[email], email)) # notice the []'s
```

But I recommend using the `.items()`( that would be `.iteritems()` if your using Python 2.x) attribute of `dict`s instead:

```
for name, email in contact_emails.items(): # .iteritems() for Python 2.x
    print('%s is %s' % (email, name))
```

---

Thanks to @PierceDarragh for mentioning that using `.format()` would be a better option for your string formatting. eg.

```
print('{} is {}'.format(email, name))
```

Or, as @ShadowRanger has also mentioned that taking advantage of prints variable number arguments, and formatting, would also be a good idea:

```
print(email, 'is', name)
```

Comment: Isn't it better to use `str.format`? `print('{} is {}'.format(name, email))` reads easier to me. Maybe it's a bit longer, but it's the more Pythonic solution anymore, I think.

Comment: @PierceDarragh Of course. I was just giving the OP back their code the way it was. But yes, `.format()` would be the way to go.

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning to the OP in your answer? I upvoted regardless, but I think some people keep using the old C-style `%` method because they don't know there's a better way!

Comment: @PierceDarragh Good idea! Thanks!

Comment: In this case, at least with Py3 `print` function, better than either version of string formatting is just letting `print` do its job: `print(email, 'is', name)`, it will convert and print one argument at a time (by default inserting spaces between items), saving the cost of even the temporary formatted string.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this would be using for/in loops to loop through each key, and for each key print each key, and then each value.

Here's how I would do it:

```
contact_emails = {
    'Sue Reyn' : 's.reyn@email.com',
    'Mike Filt': 'mike.filt@bmail.com',
    'Nate Arty': 'narty042@nmail.com'
}

for email in contact_emails:
    print (contact_emails[email] + " is " + email)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
for email in contact_emails:
    print("{} is {}".format(contact_emails[email], email))
```